# actionChangeLanguage function gives 400 invalid request error in Yii1

Tags: php, yii

```
mydomain.com/site/changeLanguage?lang=he&url=%2Fadmin%2Fdashboard
```

My sitecontroller have a actionChangeLanguage($lang, $url) function that accepts two parameters one is lang and url.

Above URL gives 400 request invalid error.

My URL Manager looks like the below:

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '/api/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/api/<action>',
                
            )
```

What can I do to resolve the above error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default it should be kebab-case-urls: mydomain.com/site/change-language?lang=he&url=%2Fadmin%2Fdashboard ....i would also recommend enable the debug-module for problems like that

Comment: @Mischa By changing as per your suggestion still it is not working.